# questions on non-metrizable weak convergence

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a normed vector space. I wonder if it is true

If $G\in X^{**}$ such that if $f_n\rightarrow f$ $weak^*$ then $G(f_n)\rightarrow G(f)$. Then $G$ is $weak^*$ continous?

thanks for any suggestions